# Python thread not setting output variable

Tags: python

So I have a simple thread that goes and performs an http request that returns a json object and I want to use json.loads to put that in to a dict specified by passing a reference to said dict.

```
def thr_get_json(host, port, path, result):
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host, port)
    conn.request('GET', path)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    if resp.status != 200:
        raise "HTTP Error!"
    result = json.loads(resp.read())

results = {}

get_thread = threading.Thread(target=thr_get_json, args=('example.com', 80, '/output.php', results))
```

For some reason, results is empty.  As it's a mutable object being passed to a function then it would be a reference right?  Or am I way out on this.

Comment: Yes, I figured that was implied, I was trying no minimise the code to read.  I was attempting to read after the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use result.update()

You just overwrote result, it's a different variable like that

(attention to the fact that you use both result (singular) and results)

Answer (score 0):

You Need to pass a Key as-well, or define a key where you would store your result:

Inside your function append the data to the dict:
result['responseData'] = json.loads(resp.read())

you can access the results by using the results['responseData'] after the thread executes

Comment: There are multiple keys, but these are provided by the json object.  results is basically an empty container.  dict.update() has solved the problem.